# Separate actions on each mouse click

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouse-listeners

I'm trying to get java to perform one action after one click and then another when the same button is pressed again, regardless of how long between clicks. Is this possible? Here's what I've tried so far:

```
button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount()%2 == 1) {
            System.out.println("You have clicked once");
        }

        if(e.getClickCount()%2 == 0){
            System.out.println("You have clicked twice");
        }
    }
});
```

This is not what I'm after because there seems to be some timer on the button to make it more like a double click. So I'm obviously using the wrong method or something but I don't know what other options there are. I want it not to matter how quickly you click the mouse again after the first click. Hope that makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If I recall correctly, `getClickCount` tells whether it was a single-click or a double-click, not the number of times it's been clicked in total. You would have to maintain some variable to keep track of it manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by using a flag. Something like:

```
private boolean isFirstClick = true;

// ...

button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(isFirstClick)
        {
             System.out.println("You have clicked once");
             isFirstClick = false;
        }
        else
        {
             System.out.println("You have clicked twice");
             isFirstClick = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Exactly -- 1+. And the general answer is to give the listener a state of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create an n-state button like this:

```
JButton button = new JButton() {
  private int state = 0;
  private int maxStates=3;
  {
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (state>=maxStates) state=0;
        switch (state++) {
          case 0:
            System.out.println("State 0");
            break;
          case 1:
            System.out.println("State 1");
            break;
          case 2:
            System.out.println("State 2");
            break;
        }
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has answered I thought I would put the solution to this.

This can be done by setting the button name or button text or any other property as you like, to be update with each mouse click and use them in a if else statement as needed. For example:

```
if(button.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Lock")) {
    mainWindowPanel.setVisible(false);
    button.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/lock-open.png")));
    button.setText("Unlock");
} else {
    mainWindowPanel.setVisible(true);
    button.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/lock.png")));
    button.setText("Lock");
}
```